# iPhone 5: Does the Wahoo Key work with the Classic-to-Lightning adapter?

Tags: hardware, compatibility, iphone

I have a [Wahoo Fisica Key](http://www.wahoofitness.com/Products/Wahoo-Fitness-Wahoo-Key-for-iPhone.asp) I use for sports. It’s is a small dongle that enables sports apps to connect to heart rate monitors, pedometers, etc. It goes into my iPhone 4 classic iPhone [30-pin-connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dock_connector#30-pin).

Wahoo’s website obviously says it does not work with the iPhone 5, but I assume this is just for the physical incompatibility of 30-pin and Lightning. When upgrading from iPhone 4 to iPhone 5, will the sensor work with the [30-pin/Lightning adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD823ZM/A/lightning-to-30-pin-adapter)?

Comment: I have no idea, but FYI Wahoo has a heart rate monitor which works without dongle on the iPhone4s + iPhone5.

Comment: Thanks @Gerry. I have just recently shelled out 115 US$ for this thing, and would prefer to keep it a while. Not only do I use a heart rate monitors, but also a stride sensor, and would hate to replace them both just for the privilege to use an iPhone 5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. According to Wahoo Support, one would be

> ... able to use the lightning adapter to continue using our Wahoo Key.
>   This would add about an inch to the bottom of the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Wahoo key and a lightning adapter and it does not work.

Comment: Have you contacted Wahoo about this? If they say it does, it should, right?